# Cannot call bson-ext's native functions

Tags: node.js, npm, bson

I am using [bson-ext](https://github.com/christkv/bson-ext) as a native binding.

Building the native `.node` file has worked well so far. I installed `GCC`, `make` and ran `node-gyp configure` and `node-gyp build`.   I am now including the file in my `node` app like so:

```
var bson =  require('./bson/build/Release/bson.node');
var object = bson.BSON.prototype;
console.log(object.serialize('hey'))
```

The problem is, I am getting this error:

> console.log(object.serialize({test: "turkey"}))
>
> TypeError: Illegal invocation

I get confused here because when I do `console.log(object)`

It outputs:

```
BSON {
calculateObjectSize: [Function: calculateObjectSize],
serialize: [Function: serialize],
serializeWithBufferAndIndex: [Function: serializeWithBufferAndIndex],
deserialize: [Function: deserialize],
deserializeStream: [Function: deserializeStream] }
```

These are the native functions from C++ that were built to `bson.node`, right? But, now I am just not sure how to call them. I have checked their github page as well for documentation, but with no luck.

**Edit**: The following:

```
var bson =  require('./bson/build/Release/bson');
console.log(bson.BSON)
```

outputs:

`[Function: BSON]`

Next, I run:

`console.log(bson.BSON().serialize({turkey: 'hey'}));`

But receive:

> console.log(bson.BSON().serialize({turkey: 'hey'}));
>
> TypeError: First argument passed in must be an array of types

Then I run:

```
 console.log(bson.BSON(['BSON']).serialize({turkey: 'hey'}));
```

And receive:

> Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

I found *a* solution inside the [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) package.

(Specifically at `\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\replset.js` @ line **15**).

They are using `.native()`

```
BSON = require('bson').native().BSON;
var newBSON = new bson();
console.log(newBSON.serialize('hello'));
```

Which does work:

```
<Buffer 32 00 00 00 02 30 00 02 00 00 00 68 00 02 31 00 02 00 00 00 65 00 02 32 00 02 00 00 00 6c 00 02 33 00 02 00 00 00 6c 00 02 34 00 02 00 00 00 6f 00 00>
```

---

However, (Slightly off-topic, but, I made a question yesterday [Why is JSON faster than BSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767310/why-is-json-faster-than-bson?rq=1), and the **conclusion** was native code vs non-native code. But, now, even after installing `bson` natively, the performance results are roughly the same... bummer.