# Why is BSON parsing faster than JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb, binary, binary-data, bson

I am trying to understand BSON in-depth. I read a few informative questions such as:
[Why is JSON faster than BSON in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767310/why-is-json-faster-than-bson-in-node-js), [Which one is lighter, JSON or BSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114932/which-one-is-lighter-json-or-bson).
But I still do not understand what makes BSON traversal is faster than JSON.

As per https://bsonspec.org/faq.html ,

> BSON is also designed to be fast to encode and decode. For example,
> integers are stored as 32 (or 64) bit integers, **so they don't need to
> be parsed to and from text**. This uses more space than JSON for small
> integers, but is much faster to parse.

I was under the assumption that computers store everything in binary. *Why is this special?*

FAQ document (above) also provides an example of BSON, but reading it I am not able to grasp why BSON is faster than JSON? Are they looking for some beginning & end characters that are BSON specific & are missing in JSON, which helps with fast traversal?

```
{"hello": "world"}
→   

  \x16\x00\x00\x00                   // total document size
  \x02                               // 0x02 = type String
  hello\x00                          // field name
  \x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00          // field value
  \x00                               // 0x00 = type EOO ('end of object')

 {"BSON": ["awesome", 5.05, 1986]}
→   
  \x31\x00\x00\x00
  \x04BSON\x00
  \x26\x00\x00\x00
  \x02\x30\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00awesome\x00
  \x01\x31\x00\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x14\x40
  \x10\x32\x00\xc2\x07\x00\x00
  \x00
  \x00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BSON parsing is faster than JSON due to its binary format, explicit type information, compactness, reduced preprocessing, and efficient data structures.

Comment: But everything is binary in a computer.  Can you provide more information?

Comment: BSON parsing is faster because it operates directly on binary data without the need for extensive character encoding and decoding, making it more efficient than JSON's text-based format.

Comment: So pretty much you don't have to deserialize data over and over again when fetching from persistent storage  & comparisons would happen directly on binary data fetched from persistent storage ? Is my understanding right? Is there more to it?

Comment: yes your are correct

Comment: So when I open a human readable text (.txt) file on my computer? Its deserialized everytime I open it?

Comment: Yes, of course. For a text file the computer even has to "guess" the character encoding.